# Doctrine 2 extra metadata in yaml

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I want to add extra metadata to the yml file describing some doctrine entity classes and their properties, that is, I want to add for each entity one or many static properties of the kind:

```
myentity:
  type: entity
  ...
  meta1: "abc" 
  meta2: "abc"
  ...
```

and do the same for each property/relationship.

Those metadata should then be reachable from inside an entity instance.

Is it possible?
How?

Comment: Have a look at     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229054/php-dictionary-class-or-alternative

Comment: Because I think you need to add a dictionary to your class to achieve your goal.